# inheritance example for mean and median

Tags: java, inheritance

I am working on mean, median in java. I have created a program but I am not able to properly implement inheritance on it. In my code, for every inherited class object, its asking input.

I want input to be taken only once and then using inheritance mean and mode to be calculated. Kindly suggest.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



class A
{

    int a[];
    int no;


    A()
    {

        System.out.println("Number of elements for an array : ");
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        no = in1.nextInt();

        a = new int[no];

        for(int i=0; i<no; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter elements : ");
            Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            a[i] = in2.nextInt();           

        }
    }

    void sort()
    {
        int tmp;
        for(int i=0; i<no-1; i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1; j<no; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("a[i] : " + a[i] + " a[i+1] : " + a[i+1]);
                if (a[i]>a[j])
                {
                    tmp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = tmp;     
                }
            }   
        }
    }


    void display()
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0; i<no; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }


}


class B extends A
{

    int tot = 0; 
    float mean;


    void get_mean()
    {
        System.out.println("no : " + no);
        for(int i=0; i<no; i++)
        {
            tot += a[i];
        }
        System.out.println("tot : " + tot);
        mean = (float) tot/no;
        System.out.println("mean : " + mean);
    }

} 


class C extends A
{

    void median()
    {
        float median;
        if(no%2==0)
        {
            int middle = no/2;
            median = (float)((a[middle] + a[middle/2])/2);
        }
        else
        {
            median = a[(no/2)];
        }
        System.out.println("median : " + median);   
    }

} 


class test
{
       public static void main (String arg[]) throws IOException
       {



        B obj1 = new B();
        obj1.get_mean();

        C obj2 = new C();
        obj2.sort();
        obj2.median();


       }
}
```

Comment: Make class C inherit from class B and the call sort, median and mean on same object. Your understanding of inheritance is wrong here. Whenever an object of derived class (B & C here) is created constructor of base class (A here) will be called. That's where its asking you input with every object created.

Comment: After changing inheritance, you should only create 1 object of type C and call median and mean methods on it.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance gives you common API and common base type not the data.

Add copy constructor which takes "A" argument and then copy properties from passed "A" object. Something like this:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class A {

    int a[];
    int no;

    A() {
    }

    void init() {

        System.out.println("Number of elements for an array : ");
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        no = in1.nextInt();

        a = new int[no];

        for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter elements : ");
            Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            a[i] = in2.nextInt();

        }
    }

    void sort() {
        int tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < no - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < no; j++) {
                System.out.println("a[i] : " + a[i] + " a[i+1] : " + a[i + 1]);
                if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                    tmp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

}

class B extends A {

    B(A obj) {
        no = obj.no;
        a = new int[obj.a.length];
        System.arraycopy( obj.a, 0, a, 0, obj.a.length );
    }

    int tot = 0;
    float mean;

    void get_mean() {
        System.out.println("no : " + no);
        for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
            tot += a[i];
        }
        System.out.println("tot : " + tot);
        mean = (float) tot / no;
        System.out.println("mean : " + mean);
    }

}

class C extends A {

    C(A obj) {
        no = obj.no;
        a = new int[obj.a.length];
        System.arraycopy( obj.a, 0, a, 0, obj.a.length );
    }

    void median() {
        float median;
        if (no % 2 == 0) {
            int middle = no / 2;
            median = ((a[middle] + a[middle / 2]) / 2);
        } else {
            median = a[(no / 2)];
        }
        System.out.println("median : " + median);
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {

        A objA = new A();
        objA.init();

        B obj1 = new B(objA);
        obj1.get_mean();

        C obj2 = new C(objA);
        obj2.sort();
        obj2.median();

    }
}
```

But better approach is to use composition rather than inheritance.
Just let your A class collect data and then inject this "data" object to B, C.
B and C dont need to be "IS-A" objects. They should be "HAS-A" objects.